# Static members in a static inner class

Tags: java

Why do we need to declare members as static in a static inner class?I think its not possible to have non static members in a static inner class then can we not simply declare members without using static keyword.

```
class MakeACaptain {
  private static MakeACaptain _captain;

  private MakeACaptain() {}

  //Bill Pugh solution
  private static class SingletonHelper {
    //Nested class is referenced after getCaptain() is called

    private static final MakeACaptain _captain = new MakeACaptain();
  }

  public static MakeACaptain getCaptain() {
    return SingletonHelper._captain;
  }
}
```

Here SingletonHelper is a static inner class

Comment: "Why do we need to declare members as static in a static inner class" [You don't need to](http://ideone.com/mBrZou). But you can.

Comment: http://ideone.com/Uw8FVp that is a static inner class with non-static members.

Comment: 'Statc inner ' is a contradiction in terms (JLS #8.1.3), and the 'need' you refer to does not exist. Obviously you haven't even tried it.

Comment: @AndyTurner so can a static inner class have non static members

Comment: @someone of course. A `static` class basically just means it doesn't enclose a reference to the outer class instance which created it.

Comment: A 'static inner ' class cannot even exist, let alone have members of any kind. You aren't making any sense.

Comment: @EJP class MakeACaptain
{
        private static MakeACaptain _captain;
        private MakeACaptain() { }

      //Bill Pugh solution
      private static class SingletonHelper{
      //Nested class is referenced after getCaptain() is called

          private static final MakeACaptain _captain = new MakeACaptain();
      }

      public static MakeACaptain getCaptain()
      {
          return SingletonHelper._captain;
      }

  } Here Singleton Helper is a inner class

Comment: @someone I'm not going to waste my precious time trying to read that mess. If you want your code read, put it into your question, and format it correctly. You are arguing with the JLS. Your question makes no sense and shows no sign of research whatsoever.

Comment: @AndyTurner But how its possible since we cannot instantiate a static class then how we will be able to use non static members

Comment: "since we cannot instantiate a static class" You clearly misunderstand what `static` means in the context of classes, because this is simply not true.

Comment: Where are you getting all this nonsense? Where does it say you can't instantiate it, and where does it say it can't have static members? NB `SingletonHelper` is *not* a 'static inner' class, and neither is anything else, as the JLS section I have already referred to states clearly.

Comment: @EJP can you now give a look

Comment: I will re-state. (1) There is no such thing as a 'static inner class': [JLS #8.1.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3). (2) Here `SingletonHelper` is a static *nested* class. (3) There is no rule against such classes having non-`static` members, as you could and should have discovered for yourself, instead of fabricating all this nonsense.

Comment: @EJP Got it.Thanks